# Unable to inherit properties from base UIViewController class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, inheritance

I'm new to iOS development and this may be a simple question. My application will have many view controllers which will share similar properties. I created a base view controller class which subclasses UIViewController. All other view controllers subclass the base view controllers. However, the properties I set in base view controller class, are not inherited. For example, the navigation bar buttons should all be the color green yet are the default blue color when I build the app.

Here's the base view controller class:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

This is the code for other view controllers that subclass the base view controller above:

```
class AboutViewController: BaseViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = NSLocalizedString("About", comment: "About page title")
}
```

I've searched the web and SO for similar questions but wasn't able to find an answer. I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with my code. I am using Xcode 7.2.1 and testing on iOS 8+. Also tested in Xcode 7.2.3 beta but had similar results.

Comment: I've just tried to create a new project and was not able to reproduce the issue. You can see for yourself by creating a new project and overriding `viewDidLoad`, just like you described. This means that the problem is somewhere else in your code base.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic Thanks for your input. I just created a new master/detail project. Only addition I made was creating a new base tableview controller class that subclasses UITableViewController. I overrode the viewDidLoad method to set the left and right barButtonItems to a certain color. I made the MasterViewController class inherit from this base view controller and the colors were still not inherited. I think I may be missing something here but still looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, this isn't an inheritance issue. If you set a break point in `viewDidLoad` of BaseViewController it does indeed execute that code. I think your issue is with how to change the tint color. Customizing the navigation bar in iOS is such a pain that I usually stray away from using navigation controller and end up just creating my own top bar view I can fully customize.

If you are trying to change the tint color of both left and right bar items for your entire app put this code in your AppDelegate file inside the `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)` function:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Here's a blog post I created that shows how to change the other colors of UINavigationBar: [Navigation Bar Colors](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/navigation-bar.html).

Comment: Thanks this may be the path I may take. I also don't think it's an inheritance issue but wondering why it does not work. I started another clean project to just test this out but faced the same issue. See my comment above